# Is DNScrypt working properly? ESET blocking

Tags: security, dns, firewall

I installed DNScrypt on Windows 7 and from a test from dnsleak.com it reroutes the DNS requests.

But: I have ESET AntiVirus installed. It has some website blocking included.
When I go to a website blocked in ESET the website cannot be opened. It can be opened using TOR browser.

Question: Is DNScrypt working properly, due to ESET blocking?

Comment: Depends.  Do you have the MITM feature enabled that allows ESET to scan secured traffic? * If you do then your security has been compromised.*

Comment: Where can I find this "feature"?